How to connect to remote Hive server from local pyspark session
I am trying to connect to a remote Hive server from my local machine via Spark but for some reason whatever operation I am doing, it is happening in my local machine, operations like saveAsTable()
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Process All Tables") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive") \
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", hive_metastore_url, conf=SparkConf()) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

What am I missing here? Is it even possible?
Note that the local machine can connect to Hive server (via workbench tools)
